# Program crashing saying that vector out of range exception

Tags: c++

My code is crashing at line 20 where I am trying to initialize name by user entered name. It seems vector is going out of range. Please help me in figure out the problem and reason behind it. 
This code takes the student data input from user, sort it based on the grades and then print it back.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct studentDatabase{
   std::string name;
   int grade;
};

void getUserInput(std::vector<struct studentDatabase> &student)
{
    std::cout << "No of students for which the data is to be entered n";
    int noOfStudents(0);
    std::cin >> noOfStudents;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < noOfStudents; ++i)
    {
       std::cout << "Enter name n";
       std::cin >> student.at(i).name;       // this is where it is crashing 
                                             //not sure why
       std::cout << "Enter grade n";
       std::cin >> student.at(i).grade;
   }
}

void sort(std::vector<struct studentDatabase> &student)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < student.size(); ++i)
    {
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < student.size() -i; j++)
        {
           if (student.at(i).grade < student.at(j).grade)
               std::swap(student.at(i), student.at(j));
        }
    }
}

void printStudentOrder(const std::vector<struct studentDatabase> &student)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < student.size(); ++i)
       std::cout << student.at(i).name << " got a grade of " << 
       student.at(i).grade << std::endl;
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<struct studentDatabase> student;
    getUserInput(student);
    sort(student);
    printStudentOrder(student);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because there are no elements in the vector and you are trying to access them. Use .push_back to add elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std::vector<studentDatabase>` intially is a empty container. So when you access the `vector` via `vector::at(i)`, no item is found and `out_of_range` exception is thrown.

You may collect the data into a local `studentDatabase` variable first, then put it into vector, like:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < noOfStudents; ++i)
{
    studentDatabase s;
    std::cout << "Enter name n";
    std::cin >> s.name;

   std::cout << "Enter grade n";
   std::cin >> s.grade;
   student.push_back(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At that point, you are trying to access an element in position `i`, but the vector is initially empty. `vector` construction doesn't behave like old-style array, where you must specify the size and all those spaces are reserved in memory.

You must **create** your vector with size like so

```
std::vector<struct studentDatabase> student(30);
getUserInput(student);
```

But if you don't know the size previously, i recommend you to get the input one by one and use `push_back()`

Answer (score 0):

Initially your vector is an empty container. so when you are trying to access the vector, it will throws an exception.

```
void getUserInput(std::vector<struct studentDatabase> &student)
{
    std::cout << "No of students for which the data is to be entered n";
    int noOfStudents(0);
    std::cin >> noOfStudents;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < noOfStudents; ++i)
    {
       studentDatabase stud;
       std::cout << "Enter name n";
       std::cin >> student.name;       // this will get student name.

       std::cout << "Enter grade n";
       std::cin >> student.grade;     // this will get student grade.

       student.push_back(stud);   // Here we are storing the data into vector.
   }
}
```

you need to store the data into vecotor to access them to avoid the exception.
Replace this code snippet with your code, your problem will be solved.